# Asking for higher salary after I increased my initial figure

Tags: salary, job-offer

I did a job interview and the hiring manager said the salary range is between $35,000 and $60,000, she asked for my salary expectations I said $38,000 (I currently earn $30,000).

After the call I realised that what I said was foolish so I sent her an e-mail that I answered prematurely and that I'm expecting from $45,000 and above.

When the offer came, they gave me $45,000, I am thinking of negotiating another $5000 on top of that amount, how do i go about that?

Comment: Note that this depends entirely on whether you are comfortable losing this offer. It's a bad idea in the sense that you're appearing flaky as described in the answer below. But if you wouldn't accept the job at less than 45+X then that is moot. If it's an otherwise excellent job and a decent enough pay raise then this is much riskier.

Comment: That seems like a broad salary range, like they are open-ended as to "level of experience" of the person being recruited perhaps? Where do you think you are relative to the job e.g fairly junior, or quite senior? On what basis did you see it was foolish to ask for $38k (an oddly specific number)?

Comment: Another thing to consider is that you're still earning 15k more than before. Why would you possibly not be happy with that?

Comment: @NikxDa Maybe they still feel underpaid? What if they were $30k below market value before, then they would now still be $15K below market value. Also, it sounds suspicious to me that the company now twice directly approved the salary that the OP asked without any negotiations; to me that's an indication that they're still being paid below market value.

Comment: @Niko1978 Still a 33% improvement in my opinion. If they really feel underpaid then they had two chances to change that. Why it's bad to get back a third time is in the answers already

Comment: @NikxDa I agree with the answers that they missed both their chances and that they shouldn't get back a third time; but that doesn't change the possibility that they still might feel underpaid, and thus still not be happy.

Comment: See how far you can take it! If they agree to $50,000, ask for $52,500 next time!

Comment: @NikxDa Maybe the new job requires moving in a big city where rent is insanely higher than at their previous location and 15k more is barely enough to cover the rent increase.

Comment: @Giacomo It's not the company's problem if the OP didn't judge the cost of living well; that's basic due diligence when applying for the job.

Comment: @JuliaHayward That's irrelevant to the comment I was replying to. NikxDa is saying "if your new job gets you 15k more than you cannot be not-satisfied" I pointed out that earning 15k more does **not** imply having an actually better wage. New jobs can come with higher expenses. NikxDa comment is completely incidental to OP issue of wanting to ask more as such my response is too irrelevant to OP question but relevant to the blanket statement made by him.

Comment: It might be ok if you talked about additional offers like a car or phone contract or home office equipment and the employer retracted that. But even then 5k is a lot on top. Another strategy would be to ask for those non-monetary add-one like Notebook, car, Support with relocation, lunch, ...

Comment: You simply will not be considered a serious person

Comment: I think this has been sufficiently answered, but another thing to consider is that companies like a candidate who knows their own worth.  By changing your salary request three times, you're clearly telling them you don't know your worth -- which is not a good look.  Stick with the offer and wait a year to ask for a raise.

Comment: please don't use comments to answer the question. Comments are temporary, use them to ask for clarification from the OP

Answer (score 177):

No.

You have already bumped them up by a significant percentage with your email; by going back on what you said a second time you will create one of two impressions - that you don't know what you actually want, or that you still won't be satisfied even if they give you more. Neither is good. Stick with the second offer, and if you really think you deserve more then ask once you've had time to prove what value you bring.

Comment: +1 The obvious reason for an employer to equal the candidate's salary request is to save the time and energy that could have been spent negotiating.

Comment: The other obvious reason could be though, that even the higher request still means a below-market salary, e.g. a bargain for the employer.

Comment: Plus probably they will no longer consider him for the position because of him being demanding?

Comment: It's possible; the fact they agreed to $45k without pushback probably means they are still in budget, and they have already named $60k as the top of their range, but obviously there are red lines _somewhere_ in both money and HR's patience.

Comment: Continuing to negotiate after having agreed is a red flag to an Employer

Comment: An option for OP is to request benefits not direct compensation if they want more.

Answer (score 60):

No way. You already asked for more. If I was the hiring manager and you asked again I would rescind your offer.

You got a nice increase in salary.  Be happy.  Take the job and stop  negotiating.

Answer (score 57):

It would show two things about you:

1- You are completely money driven and will jump ship at the first opportunity - hence you're a bad investment for the company

2- You don't think things through - hence you're a bad investment for the company

You will very possibly find they rescind the offer.

Answer (score 3):

The following applies to anything that has a price:

Changing a price before the other side reacts is poor negotiation, but can be written off as a mistake.

Changing a price after the other side agrees is an insult.

Answer (score -1):

I'm honestly not sure how realistic the idea of them rescinding the offer is. I would think that the worst case is that they simply say they won't meet the new demand. It depends on how urgently you need this job and if other offers are on the table.

If you have some time, you could try getting an offer from another company for more and letting the first company know you'd be willing to work for them if they can match it. There may not be enough time though given the context.

Generally when negotiating salaries you never want to give the opening offer or your current salary. This way if they want to give you more than what you thought you'd get then they won't come down to it.

Answer (score -5):

Other answers say “no” and I initially thought the same, but I’m going to suggest a slightly different approach.

There is a way you **could** (note the emphasis on the conditional) get out of this with $50,000 (what you seem to be wanting now), but it will take more than just “oh sorry I changed my mind”. If you do that you’ll be crammed, and rightly so.

Basically, your only way forward at this point is to wait for a few days and let this company know that you really, crazily want to work with them (and explain why), however you just received an offer from another company for $52,000. Obviously you thinking about it because $7,000 is quite a difference. However, if they’re willing to bump you to $50,000 it would then be a case closed and you guarantee them that you will join and don’t do any further discussions, and you’ll be extremely grateful for their patience.

Also, if and when you do that, explicitly mention that you’re embarrassed and aware of the fact that you’re borderline, and also insist that you thank them for having already agreed for $45,000. Phrase it like you’re not playing a numbers game, and the only reason for this behavior is that you can’t easily let go of a 7,000 difference because you have responsibilities and all the likes. Your family wouldn’t be happy for instance, or you have student debt, etc.

I’m not saying that it *will* work. It very well might not work and still cram you, depending on how you did during the interviews. I’m just saying that this is the only sensible scenario in which it might have a slight chance to work.

Be aware that if they go along with that, you’d better perform exceptionally well once on the job, or else you’ll be dumped at the first review (and very likely before that).

Comment: I am not sure that lying is a good advice...

Comment: And what happens when they call your bluff?

Comment: This is really bad form. For one, it's a blatant lie, and if you're caught, you're out of there. But also, there's tons of questions on this site about what happens when people get raises that result from other offers, and the overwhelming consensus is that that person's days are numbered at that company.

Comment: This is awful advice.

Comment: Honesty is the best policy. This is absolutely the wrong way to start a new job.

Comment: Who says this answer implies lying? If the candidate has the skills needed to top $50,000, then it's very likely he could manage to get another offer on the line at this level. This answer of course implies that he manages to find such an offer, and that this would be a way for him to get to the level he ultimately wants, with the company he's currently in discussions with.

Comment: @Jivan You explicitly state that the asker should tell the company he has another higher offer when there is no indication that is true.  That is flat out lying.  If such an offer doesn't exist, the asker isn't going to wait a week or more to secure such an offer and you clearly weren't advocating that.

Comment: @Steve-o169 that's your interpretation. Another view is that the OP likely has a few other offers popping up almost daily, because he likely has applied to many different offers in the past few weeks. One of these offers could get him a $52,000 opportunity, and if this is the case, he might use it the way I described.

Comment: There's nothing to interpret. The OP had an interview and an offer.  There's no mention of other offers.  The question has nothing to do with playing multiple offers off each other -- the asker is only trying to judge how he will appear if he attempts to get an even higher salary than he's already negotiated.  Lying about another offer to increase the salary further is not good advice.

Comment: @Steve-o169 you seem to be more concerned about the fact that lying would be "bad" (in the moral sense) than that it would be "bad advice" (as in, could ultimately hurt the interests of the OP). In this situation, lying being "bad advice" is largely debatable and up to the OP to decide. On the other hand, lying being "bad" (morally) is irrelevant. Not saying I don't agree with you (I do to an extent), just saying it's not the point.

Comment: Where do my comments mention anything about morality?  In terms of professionalism and in the eyes of employers, lying is bad advice.  It very well could hurt the OP if the company calls his bluff and rescinds their offer, leaving OP with NO offers.  Not even sure what's up for debate here.

Comment: *One of these offers could get him a $52,000 opportunity, and if this is the case* if that really is the case, he should just take that other offer and stop wasting this employer's time. And, if I were an employer and a candidate told me this, that's exactly what I'd tell them.

Comment: @Jivan Since you don't seem to understand the consequences of getting caught lying in your professional life let's spell it out: If I catch a potential employee intentionally lying during the hiring process, not only will they be blacklisted from the current company, it's also very likely that friends and acquaintances in the area will learn about this as well with the obvious consequences. A bad reputation travels incredibly fast in most professions.

Comment: And worst case scenario: Getting terminated a few years after being hired for lying during the hiring process will wreak havoc to your CV. Any potential employer inquiring about you at that job will immediately remove you from consideration. Leaving a long hole in your CV will inevitably bring up questions and I assume your next step would then be to lie some more.

Comment: @Voo would you stop this hypocritical nonsense one second please? What will really happen if you find out that your best skilled and most-valuable worker lied about a previous position in order to get the job, is that you’ll thank him for having done that. If the guy is crap of course it will be different, but then he’d be crap anyway so won’t make much of a difference whether he lied or not.

Comment: @Jivan Thank you for telling me what I'd do in such a situation. Your ethical compass might be askew, but that doesn't mean that the rest of the world shares your attitude. And do I really have to link you reports of people being fired for lying? This is not a novel concept and has happened before. You could also look up "After-Acquired Evidence" to see other fun consequences.

Comment: How about bosses who tell their employee that project ABC is due for 1st of March, but in fact was due for 15th, the boss simply wanted the employee to feel a little pressure to make sure said project would be actually ready for the 15th. Ever heard of such thing? I have, numerous times. Is it a lie according to your ethical compass? Is it something reprehensible, or is it "for the benefit of the company, and hence for the benefit of the worker by repercussion"?

Comment: "If I catch a potential employee intentionally lying during the hiring process, not only will they be blacklisted from the current company, it's also very likely that friends and acquaintances in the area will"... ask what the candidate lied about.  Was it their education?  Prior work experience?  Level of responsibility at a previous job?  Certifications?  When these friends and colleagues find out you are running a blacklist based on "probably lied about competing offers", it is you and not the job seeker who will have the bad reputation.

Comment: @Ben **If** I found out they lied, is very different from "probably lied". Obviously you want to have definite proof for these things - which might very well be hard to establish here and you could get away with it, no doubt. But are you really saying you'd hire someone who intentionally lied to you to get the job or more money during the interview process?

Comment: 'Lying being "bad" (morally) is irrelevant'.  OOOOOOOFF that's..... very questionable. And some people won't do what's morally bad, because... well, they have an ethical sense and realize you shouldn't do these things. If you are ok with lying, then go for it. The community kinda seems to be against you that this is good advice, though :/. (and btw, "other ppl lie this way" doesn't give you any ethical right to do the same. And you can't even know if Voo is the kind to do that, so bringing this into question is just a bad way to deflect...)

Comment: @All: give me one example of someone who doesn’t slightly pump up the figure when asked “what’s your previous/current salary”. Like, really was 50, pretending was 55. That’s the definition of a lie, and virtually anyone I can think of has done that. Pretending that it’s unacceptable/unfair/scandalous/etc while invoking subsequent legal actions sounds like a way for the “lying by exaggeration” practice (which any salesman in the world and any business negotiator in the world is guilty of) to remain an exclusive owner/employer’s privilege, to which employees/candidates must not have access.

Comment: @Voo: I would have zero tolerance of a lie "to get the job".  Those involve credentials.  I would have significant tolerance of someone's claims about their market value.  And you are talking about a claim that cannot be disproven, unless the candidate is dumb enough to say who made the competing offer.  Of course if they want so far as to fabricate an offer letter and forge someone's signature, then that should disqualify them.

Comment: @Ben That's why I said "if you get caught". If you don't - well people get away with stuff all the time. But people are also stupid and get caught up in unnecessary lies (most people are very uncomfortable liars). If I don't have definite proof, I certainly wouldn't do anything. For such a grave accusation you should never rely on gut feeling. Also I wouldn't ask people what they earned in their previous job, but what they want to earn for their current job - it's an incredibly unfair question (but note the company in this case asked for what he wanted, which is a fair question).

Comment: @Voo: There's a difference between "not caught" and "not falsifiable".  Claims about how much you can make elsewhere are not falsifiable.  Partly because no one can ever check an offer discussed in a private conversation with a party you don't know, and partly because the claim is so vague.  Is it more money for the exact same number of hours of the exact same work in the exact same location?  Obviously not; every job is different in some way.  But a claim to be offered more elsewhere is *subjective*, and punishment is only appropriate for making claims that are false *objectively*.

Comment: @Ben But the idea was to claim "a company is offering me X" which is a decidable statement that's objectively either true or false (contrary to say "I'm worth X") - you either got that offer or you didn't. Granted it's unlikely that you'd get caught, although certainly not impossible if you're particularly inapt. Just to be clear: I'm talking about a candidate intentionally making an objectively untrue statement to better their position, nothing else. Which is what the poster here proposes. Your examples fall short on this and I quite agree that a different reaction would be appropriate.